# Hibernate 4.0.1 to 4.3.5: Unable to make JDBC Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, derby

I have a project that uses Hibernate 4.0.1 to interact with a derby database. That works fine. Here is a sample program that simply connects to the database and doesn't do anything:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DbTestMain {
    public static void main(String... args){
        Configuration derbyConfiguration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate-derby.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory derbySF = derbyConfiguration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session derbySession = derbySF.openSession();

        derbySession.close();
    }
}
```

And here is the corresponding config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby:TestDerbyDB;create=true</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my classpath:

[image]

That works fine. But when I try to update to Hibernate 4.3.5, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\TestDerbyDB;create=true]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at DbTestMain.main(DbTestMain.java:9)
```

The only thing I've done is change my classpath to use Hibernate 4.3.5:

[image]

(For some reason, Hibernate 4.0.1 requires commons-collections, but Hibernate 4.3.5 does not.)

I'm not changing anything else, and the error message is frustratingly vague. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Did something change that I need to update in my code?

My actual scenario is that I'm trying to pull code from an old (Hibernate 4.0.1) project and put it into a newer (Hibernate 4.3.5) project.

Comment: Looks like something is definitely broken in hibernate. Have you tried using the new  TenSevenDialect? `org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect` is outdated as far as I know.

Comment: It looks a little odd that "derbyclient.jar" comes from "DatabaseLocalizer/lib", while "derby-10.10.2.0.jar" comes from "StaticVoidGames/target". Maybe you've got some classpath collisions going on? Also, since your JDBC Connection URL is an Embedded URL, not a Client URL, you can remove derbyclient.jar from your classpath entirely.

Comment: @BryanPendleton That's a symptom of my actual use case: I've got two existing project: StaticVoidGames that uses Hibernate 4.3.5, and DatabaseLocalizer that uses Hibernate 4.0.1. I'm trying to take code from DatabaseLocalizer and use it in StaticVoidGames, but I get the above error. To track down the cause, I created a third project with the MCVE, and started it out with DatabaseLocalizer's classpath. That worked fine, so I replaced each jar with one from StaticVoidGames's classpath, until I narrowed it down to the core Hibernate jar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latest Hibernate and Derby: Unable to make JDBC Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812429/latest-hibernate-and-derby-unable-to-make-jdbc-connection)