# Latest Hibernate and Derby: Unable to make JDBC Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jdbc, derby

I'm trying to create a barebones project that uses Hibernate to connect to a Derby database. I'm using the latest versions of both Hibernate and Derby, but I get a generic `Unable to make JDBC Connection` error.

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>StaticVoidGames</groupId>
    <artifactId>DatabaseTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DatabaseTest</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.12.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.12.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is my `hibernate-derby-cfg.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby:TestDerbyDB;create=true</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my barbones code:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DatabaseTestMain {
    public static void main(String... args){
        Configuration derbyConfiguration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate-derby.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory derbySF = derbyConfiguration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session derbySession = derbySF.openSession();

        derbySession.close();
    }
}
```

When I run that, I get this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at DatabaseTestMain.main(DatabaseTestMain.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:derby:TestDerbyDB;create=true]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
```

I have tried changing my sql dialect to use Derby 10.7:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</property>
```

And I have tried changing my `pom.xml` to use Derby 10.7:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.7.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.7.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But no matter what I do, I still get the above error. Am I missing something?

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683790/hibernate-4-0-1-to-4-3-5-unable-to-make-jdbc-connection) about this same problem while upgrading from Hibernate 4.0.1 to Hibernate 4.3.5. There were a few questions about where my classpath was coming from, upgrading to a newer version, etc. So I tried starting over with a completely new project with the newest versions of everything, but I'm still getting the error.

**Edit:** I should note that all of these settings worked fine in Hibernate 4.0.1, and Derby databases don't require a username or password.

Comment: <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property> is blank... should you be adding it?

Comment: Have you tried setting username to "sa" (no passwd) and setting "hbm2ddl.auto" to "create"? There must be more causes in the stack trace.

Comment: @codeMan Derby databases don't require a username or password.

Comment: @Stefan There are not more causes in the stack trace. That is the entire stack trace. I should also note that this worked fine in Hibernate 4.0.1.

Comment: Is there any specific need to use ClientDriver but not EmbeddedDriver?

Comment: @Stefan If I change the username to sa and the auto setting to create, I get teh same error. This works with Hibernate 4.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ClientDriver` to connect to a local database. The recent derby documentation (at the time of writing) says that

> The class that loads Derby's local JDBC driver is the class
>   `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`. The class that loads Derby's
>   network client driver is the class `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`.

Please refer https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefjdbc32052.html

So in order for your code to run, I would suggest you to `EmbeddedDriver` if you don't want much of the changes. Incase if you still have to use `ClientDriver`, then you will have to [**run the network service instance**](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html#start_ns) change the connection URL to something like `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest;create=true` and also you **must have to provide both username and password for** `ClientDriver`.

Comment: Switching to `EmbeddedDriver` does seem to fix it. This worked in Hibernate 4.0.1 though- do you know when they changed this?

Comment: Hibernate has undergone many changes internally over time. The way it registers driver and handling connection properties etc.
For example., If you try `System.out.println( DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:derby:").
                getClass());` in your code you will be amazed of what the actual driver is...